# InfiniDB on Windows: configuration

Tags: mysql, infinidb

I'm currently trying to set up an instance of Calpont's [InfiniDB](http://infinidb.org/) on Windows, however I'm currently struggling against a problem:

I set everything up on my development server, created the database, tables etc. Now I want to access the db from my development machine and I can't seem to configure things so that the development machine can connect. In other words, it seems like for the moment I'm only able to connect from 127.0.0.1

I found a manual that details configuration for Linux, but failed to find equivalent commands on Windows.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not detailed in the documentation from what I could gather, the way to grant access seems to be through the mysql prompt using a GRANT command.